# How to handle the wndproc calcsize process in the form to do customization without affecting the behavior

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developing a custom form that provides more options to customize the appearance of the form. I have override the wndproc and calculated the size of the form in calcsize()method while getting message 131 in wndproc. I have done the calculation to customize the height of the titlebar in calcsize().Please refer the following code below.The problem is while opening the form with borderstyle sizeablewindowtool in windows 10 and 8,the form goes inside the taskbar(its a behavior of the msdn form).But the problem is while im opening the form in the windows 7, the form goes inside the taskbar.I have checked with the msdn form its not going inside the taskbar for windows 7. Please help me to find my mistake.

```
  /// <summary>
        /// Calculates the non client area of the form
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="m">reference message</param>
        /// <returns>retruns true if the method returns combiantion of values
        /// returns false if the method return zero</returns>
        private bool OnWmNcCalcSize(ref Message m)
        {
            NativeMethods.RECT rc = (NativeMethods.RECT)m.GetLParam(typeof(NativeMethods.RECT));

            int iBorderWidth = fl.BorderWidth;

                fl.PerformLayout(rc.Width, rc.Height);
                rc.top += fl.CaptionHeight;
                if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
                {
                    ///<summary>
                    /// local variable to store x-coordinate of native rectangle,rc.left is -6 when we double click on title-bar and -8 when we click the maximize button.
                    ///</summary>
                    int xcoordinate = rc.left;
                    rc.left -= xcoordinate;
                    rc.right += xcoordinate;
                    rc.bottom += xcoordinate;
                }
                else
                {
                    rc.left += iBorderWidth - (iBorderWidth / 3);
                    rc.right -= iBorderWidth - (iBorderWidth / 3);
                    rc.bottom -= iBorderWidth - (iBorderWidth / 3);
                }

                Marshal.StructureToPtr(rc, m.LParam, true);
            m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: What is a msdn Form? What is `this.FrameLayout` and the related `FrameLayoutInfo` object? What is the use of this: `using (CaptionManager cm = new CaptionManager(this, true)) { base.WndProc(ref m); }` (it never gets into play)? + You need to calculate the invisible border of the Form's frame (if this is actually a native Windows Forms object).

Comment: Hi Jimi,this.FrameLayout ,FrameLayoutInfo these are just to get the form caption settings.using (CaptionManager cm = new CaptionManager(this, true)) { base.WndProc(ref m); } sorry for this unwanted code,I have included other fix.I have removed those code.

Comment: Hi Jimi,how to calculate the invisible border.

Comment: See the [SystemInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.systeminformation) class, `Border3DSize`, `BorderSize`, `BorderMultiplierFactor`, `CaptionHeight`, `CaptionButtonSize` etc. You shouldn't be handling the `WM_NC***` messages (maybe `WM_NCHITTEST`, which isn't strictly required either). You're trying to convert non-client are into client area, but you're not even handling the negative values you receive when the Form is minimized. If you want to add a custom (themed?) Caption bar, you're far away.

Comment: Sorry Jimi in need of changing the height of the titlebar.Also i have do customization in border width.So i have to handle calcsize. Is there any other way to fix this issue. thanks for your valuable comments

Comment: Since Vista, custom non-client frames are done with [DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmextendframeintoclientarea) A test  => [Test custom caption](https://i.ibb.co/FxmczsM/Custom-Caption2.jpg)