# Getting Wrong size while passing the rectangle to AdjustWindowRectEx() in 4.0 framework?

Tags: c#, winforms

Im creating the custom form. I have tried to get the window size. I have passed the rectangle(0,0,0,0) to the AdjustWindowRectEx(). I have getting the wrong rectangle(-3,26,3,3). This issue occurs only when the project is opened in framework 4.0 and form borderstyle is fixed single. While for the 4.6 frame work the rectangle value is (-8,31,8,8). I dont know how it works. The issue occurs only in the 4.0 frame work and borderstyle is fixedsingle. Please find the code snippet below.

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
                AdjustWindowRectEx(ref rectangle, this.CreateParams.Style, false, this.CreateParams.ExStyle);
            }

            [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            static extern bool AdjustWindowRectEx(ref Rectangle rc, Int32 dwStyle, bool bMenu, Int32 dwExStyle);
    }
```

Comment: It's not wrong. Those are the same metrics computed using the values returned by `GetWindowRect` and `GetClientRect`. It applies to that window class. If you change Framework version, `GetWindowRect` and `GetClientRect` return different values. That's just how the window is built (and the theme applied). What are you using `AdjustWindowRectEx` for? It's used internally, constantly, to set the values of the Form's standard properties. You can just use those.

Comment: Btw, that function is not DpiAware, if you really need it, you should use [AdjustWindowRectExForDpi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-adjustwindowrectexfordpi) instead. Provided that your app is also DpiAware, otherwise any window measure is *virtual*.

Comment: Hi Jimi, Im using the property to calculate the window size. But i dont know why the rect differs depends on the FrameWork version. And specifically for version 4.0  and while the border style is fixed(and works fine for sizeable borderstyle). your info is clear. Still im confused why the value differs only for specific version(4.0).

Comment: Not version 4.0, but up to version 4.0. Applies to all FWs from Whidbey to 4.0. The value of `SystemInformation.FixedFrameBorderSize` is not used after (long story). You can just set the `ClientSize` property, then see what the `Size` has been set to. I'm not sure what are you using this for, but maybe the notes here: [Create Form.MinimumClientSize Property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59797946/7444103) may be useful. Note that you can read `this.Size - this.ClientSize`.

Comment: hi Jimi,Im  creating the custom form. Already we have discussed about it this thread. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56735401/how-to-handle-the-wndproc-calcsize-process-in-the-form-to-do-customization-witho

Comment: Im have customized the caption bar, and also applied theme accordingly. But the problem araises while getting the windowrect. Its various depends on OS and frameWork. So how can make a generic calculation. I have done many of the issues depends on the OS and its not the generic way of fixing. Now I have found that the WindowRect differs depends on the frame work too. So can i find any generic fix without the condition check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210413/discussion-between-sam10-and-jimi).